# Can I use the 'like' operator in sql in order for the user to input the table he wants?

Tags: sql, operator-keyword, ms-access-2013

I want to make a query in order for the user to inputs the name of a table and then it shows him the results of that table. Is that possible? I am using Access 2013.

Comment: Where would you like to do this from?  Just running a query?  A form?  Something else?

Comment: I'm having no luck doing it from a query, but from a form shouldn't be too difficult.  I assume the person would enter like 'abc' and tblAbc, tblILoveAbcs, and tblAbcNews would all open?

Comment: I want it from a query not from a form unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

You may try the syntax below :

`SELECT Table.column FROM Table
WHERE (((Table.column) Like "*" & [your message to prompt input:] & "*"));`

Comment: No, I want the user to input the Table not what to Select. So I want something like this : SELECT * FROM (user inputs a name)